# How to start -up oracle through script?

Tags: oracle

I am trying to startup oracle script but getting sqlplus error,

```
###to bring-up ethernet interface
ifup em1;

###to startup oracle default instance but throws error
su -l oracle -c 'sqlplus / as sysdba; startup'

###to startup oracle listener
su -l oracle 'lsnrctl start xe_lsnr'
```

Please guide me in starting up oracle through script.

Answer (score 1):

Are we to guess what the error is?  What is the context of this script? why are you also trying to start an ethernet interface in the same script? Why are you obviously starting off as root instead of oracle?

Your su command to start sqlplus terminates with the semicolon. It doesn't pass the 'startup' to sqlplus, but tries to continue shell process with 'startup' *after* sqlplus exits and control returns back to the shell processor.

I could show how to work around it, but I strongly feel that you are approaching the entire issue of starting the database in the wrong way. If this is supposed to be part of a sever startup, see "[Automating Shutdown And Startup](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UNXAR/strt_stp.htm#UNXAR150)" in the *Database Administrator's Reference*.

That said, personally I do not want my databases starting automatically. If my linux servers have to go down for any reason, I want to be there at startup to check things out before allowing my database to start.